# What's this edited image with a man lying in bed and a spectre haunting him from?

Tags: wanren-yehua

I was looking at [this Buzzfeed page](http://www.buzzfeed.com/kevintang/baffling-out-of-context-screenshots-from-anime-and-manga) and have been trying to figure out the series some of these screencaps belong to. I managed to find a lot of them by a combination of reverse image search and looking up the quoted text, but I'm not sure about [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8d6l.jpg). (Note: some offensive language that I edited out.)

I didn't have much success with a reverse Google image search, although I did find out from [one of the results](https://imgur.com/gallery/2A85Bkn) that the text was probably edited in by someone. (The link here also contains the original profanity, which I blacked out in the image in the first link.) Since I can't remove the text without also editing the rest of the image (at least with my rather limited image editing tools), I don't think I'll have much success finding what this is originally from by simply erasing the text (e.g. by making it grey) and searching with that either.

From the Imgur link, it's clear that this is originally probably from a horror manga.

**Update:** I found an unedited version of the image, which is below. Still haven't had any luck with reverse image searches, so I'll probably try looking at lists of horror manga and possible TV Tropes pages later. As such I removed the earlier image from the post so as to avoid redundancy (and added a link to it).

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With some google research I found that it comes from a manhwa whose chinese name is 
**万人夜话**: I don't know if there is an English translation of that. Maybe someone who understand Chinese knows the translated title (if it exists).

[This](http://www.dm5.com/m50628/#ipg23) is the link to the scan from which the picture is taken (vol. 5).

Comment: I salute your google-fu! AFAIK, there is no English translation. I would translate the title literally as "Ten Thousand People's Night Talks".

Comment: @GaoWeiwei: Seems accurate. I tried looking up Baidu and similar sites to see if there was a synopsis somewhere, but unfortunately had no luck.

Comment: It is basically the Cantonese version of [Fuan no Tane](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=11555), a collection of very short and mostly atmospheric stories dealing with urban legends, ghosts and superstitions all organized around a specific theme (school, visitors etc.).